# How do I change the visibility of a view?

Tags: android, view

How do I change the visibility of my custom view?

I know how to do it with a listview(- getListView().setVisibility(View.GONE) -) but I don't know how to do it with my custom view "compview" defined in the xml like this:

```
<View android:id="@+id/compview" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have called `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` you can call `findViewById(R.id.compview)` and than use `setVisibility()` like you mentioned it above.

Comment: There are no dumb questions, there are only dumb answers :)